# Using Fermat's descent to find sum of squares for a prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, infinite-descent

I am finding the sum of squares for 1973.

I was given the initial expression:

${259}^2+1^2=\ 34\cdot1973$

and using descent have gotten it down to

$\left(53\right)^2+\left(84\right)^2=5\cdot 1973$

I am using the formula u = A (mod M) and v = B (mod M), where A = 53, B = 84, and M = 53. However, I get a 4 and 3 for u,v. This, however, doesn't get me the correct result. I am using the text: A Friendly Introduction to Number Theory.

[image]

[image]

Comment: $M=5$, and use $-\frac M2\le u,v\le\frac M2$.

Comment: @mathlove using just that formula, we can say that u,v = 1,2, but does this satisfy the mod equation? that u = A mod M and v = B mod M?

Comment: I obtained $u=-2,v=-1$.